# Multi war deployment on heroku or cloudfoundry?

Tags: java, heroku, cloud-foundry

Using the following
[java buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git)
how would I be able to deploy a multi-war application?

What I did was zipped up the tomcat root dir, contains the common,conf, shared and webapps
directories, and named the zip a war and then deploy using that "war" which contains everything. But it seems to fail at staging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible with the Java Build pack that you listed.  It's designed to deploy *one* WAR file as *one* application on CF.  If you have multiple applications, you would simply push multiple separate application to CF.

If you insist on pushing multiple WAR files into a single CF application, you'll need to customize or create your own build pack.

Comment: Unfortunately, the app was developed in such a way by die dev's that I have to deploy it together. In the end I just created a buildpack myself, which worked for us.